# How to integrate Julia with a HTML web page - how to call a Julia function from an application running in a web browser

Tags: api, rest, julia

we have a Julia language calculation engine we want to trigger on command from a HTML webpage.

How can I connect from this application to a Julia instance. Is it possible to connect to Julia via a REST service?

Comment: Hi and welcome to Stack Overflow, please take a time to go through the [welcome tour](https://stackoverflow.com/tour) to know your way around here (and also to earn your first badge), read how to create a [Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) and also check [How to Ask Good Questions](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) so you increase your chances to get feedback and useful answers.

Comment: while this question is not perfect the answer provided by Matt B is very useful for others. Maybe it would be better to edit it instead of closing it.

Answer (score 7):

You just need to have Julia listening on a port for incoming requests and have it respond accordingly.  You can use an HTTP package (like [HTTP.jl](https://juliaweb.github.io/HTTP.jl/stable/)) to easily set up a [REST](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Representational_state_transfer) endpoint:

```
import HTTP
using Sockets
compute(req::HTTP.Request) = HTTP.Response(200, "hello world")
const SERVER = HTTP.Router()
HTTP.@register(SERVER, "GET", "/test", compute)
HTTP.serve(SERVER, ip"127.0.0.1", 12345)
```

Now accessing `http://127.0.0.1:12345/test` should show you a page with the string hello world on it.

There are many frameworks that build atop this basic paradigm.

Comment: If you want to run this in Linux from an address like 163.67.87.54 you need to change ip"127.0.0.1" with ip"0.0.0.0". The call will be: 163.67.87.54:12345/test

Comment: Yes, 0.0.0.0 will expose the service to the internet, whereas 127.0.0.1 will be localhost-only.  Cf. https://superuser.com/questions/949428/whats-the-difference-between-127-0-0-1-and-0-0-0-0